# Function Parameter is "#define"?

Tags: visual-c++

Something weird I've never come across before. I wrote this function for one of my school projects:

```
void j_glOrtho(int left, int right, int bottom, int top, float near, float far)
```

For some reason Microsoft Visual C++ says that `near` and `far` are `#define` instead of `float`. As a result, I get a compiler error when I try to use them as `float`s. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I bang my head multiple times against my keyboard when this happens.

Comment: @Marlon: That makes me worry -- be careful the keyboard doesn't break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's some legacy compatibility for DOS and 16-bit things. I'm not sure if this will work, but try it:

```
#ifdef near
#undef near
#endif
#ifdef far
#undef far
#endif
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I doubt I ever would have found that out myself. Strange thing though.

Comment: @Jesse: I'm not sure if this would've worked here, but when you don't know what an identifier is referring to, F12 is your friend. :)